# does bcoin support simplified payment verification (SPV)?

Tags: spv, bcoin

Does bcoin support simplified payment verification (SPV)? I can't seem to find anything about it online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it supports SPV out of the box. Bcoin actually started out as an SPV project according to Buck Perley.

Here is an example on how to start up a bcoin node in spv

https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/blob/master/docs/Examples/spv-sync-wallet.js